# How to plot shapes on main chart from a script that loads in a different panel?

Tags: pine-script

I am modifying an ADX + DI script, which loads in a different panel from the main chart.

I have created some **plotshapes**, which appear in the ADX indicator panel.

How can I make them appear on the main chart, above/below price bars?

Here is my script - my shapes are at the bottom titled 'PULLBACK STUDY':

```
study("DC - ADX and DI", overlay=true)
len = input(title="Length", type=integer, defval=10)
th = input(title="Threshold", type=integer, defval=20)
diMinusThreshold = input(title="DIMinus Threshold", type=integer, defval=17)
diPlusThreshold = input(title="DIPlus Threshold", type=integer, defval=17)
pullbackThreshold = input(title="Pullback Threshold", type=integer, defval=7)

TrueRange = max(max(high-low, abs(high-nz(close[1]))), abs(low-nz(close[1])))
DirectionalMovementPlus = high-nz(high[1]) > nz(low[1])-low ? max(high-nz(high[1]), 0): 0
DirectionalMovementMinus = nz(low[1])-low > high-nz(high[1]) ? max(nz(low[1])-low, 0): 0


SmoothedTrueRange = nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1]) - (nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1])/len) + TrueRange
SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus = nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus[1]) - (nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus[1])/len) + DirectionalMovementPlus
SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus = nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus[1]) - (nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus[1])/len) + DirectionalMovementMinus


DIPlus = SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus / SmoothedTrueRange * 100
DIMinus = SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus / SmoothedTrueRange * 100
DX = abs(DIPlus-DIMinus) / (DIPlus+DIMinus)*100
ADX = sma(DX, len)


plot(DIPlus, color=green, title="DI+")
plot(DIMinus, color=red, title="DI-")
plot(ADX, color=gray, title="ADX")
hline(th, color=gray, linestyle=dashed)


// PULLBACK STUDY
priceDropping = DIMinus >= diMinusThreshold ? red : na
bgcolor(priceDropping,90)

priceRising = DIPlus >= diPlusThreshold ? green : na
bgcolor(priceRising,90)

possiblePullbackBear = DIMinus >= diMinusThreshold and (DIMinus - DIPlus <= 16) and rising(DIPlus, 1)
plotshape(possiblePullbackBear, style=shape.triangledown, color=red, location=location.top)

possiblePullbackBull = DIPlus >= diPlusThreshold and (DIPlus - DIMinus <= 16) and rising(DIMinus, 1)
plotshape(possiblePullbackBull, style=shape.triangleup, color=green, location=location.bottom)
```

Comment: PS - I believe this is a version 3 script that I'm working with; not sure if that will cause an issue (ie if it needs to be migrated to ver 4)...

Comment: Not possible. The single option for a script that is loaded on a separate pane to plot/draw somthing on the chart pane at the same time - is to use 'barcolor()' function that will assign colors to price bars/candles. Any 'plot()', 'plotshape()' etc will be only drawn on the indicator's pane.